# Javascript upload folder by zipping with same folder structure as uploaded folder has

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file-upload

How to zip a selected folder on upload functionality in client side using javascript. I have a Folder upload button it will open folder selection window, upon selection of a folder, I want to zip the folder with same folder structure and upload to the backend server.

---

**Upon Research:** Found below method to create Zip, I can able to create the Zip for all the files within the folder even files are in subfolder its creating zip of all the files in the same folder.

But I want to zip in the same folder structure.

Below is my code and used library reference:

Click link : [JSFidler](https://jsfiddle.net/yogeeshsj/9npbu7xk/16/)

https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip

The Javascript method as follows:

```
          <-- HTML !-->
          <input id="uploadID" type="file" accept=".zip" webkitdirectory> 

          //Javascript
          uploadfolder(e){
            var zip = new JSZip();
            var fileslist = event.target.files;
            var files = zip.folder();
            for(let i=0; i<fileslist.length; i++){
                console.log(fileslist[i].name);
                files.file(fileslist[i].name, fileslist[i].raw, {base64: true});
            }
            zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
                saveAs(content, "example.zip");
            });
           },
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at these URLs

```
  https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-folder
  https://stuk.github.io/jszip/
```

Comment: I have used https://stuk.github.io/jszip/, Now I can able to create Zip of all the files in folder and sub-folders to the common folder, but folder structure needs to be in same as uploaded folder.

Please check the JSFidler: https://jsfiddle.net/yogeeshsj/9npbu7xk/16/

Comment: @YOGEESH I found a way to preserve the folder structure using webkitRelativePath JSFidler: https://jsfiddle.net/ukx307fd/

Answer (score 1):

I literally searched the whole Internet for a solution to this question but couldn't find any. The one that came close was https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/386#issuecomment-634773343 , which again is not exactly what I was looking for. Tried solving it myself and here is what I came up with

```
const recursivelyZipFolders = (
folder: JSZip,
pathArray: string[],
currentIndex: number,
file: File
) => {
const subFolder = folder.folder(pathArray[currentIndex])!;
currentIndex += 1;
if (currentIndex < pathArray.length - 1) {
    recursivelyZipFolders(subFolder, pathArray, currentIndex, file);
} else {
    subFolder.file(pathArray[pathArray.length - 1], file);
}
};

export const getFilesAsZip = async (files: File[]) => {
try {
    const zip = new JSZip();
    files.forEach((file: any) => {
        // make sure it works for both drag && drop, as well as click & upload 
        const pathArray = file.path
            ? file.path.split("/")
            : file.webkitRelativePath.split("/");
        if (file.path) {
            pathArray.shift();
        }
        if (pathArray.length === 2) {
            zip.file(pathArray[1], file);
        } else if (pathArray.length > 2) {
            const folder = zip.folder(pathArray[1])!;
            if (pathArray.length === 3) {
                folder.file(pathArray[2], file);
            } else {
                recursivelyZipFolders(folder, pathArray, 2, file);
            }
        }
    });
    // zip object now maintains the original folder structure
    return await zip.generateAsync({
        type: "blob",
        compression: "DEFLATE",
        compressionOptions: {
            level: 9,
        },
    });
} catch (error) {
    throw error;
}
};
```

It was tested for folders with upto five sub folders and seemed to work fine. Open to further improvements and optimizations.